# how do I make an input equal to a line from another file

Tags: python

I have to create a game that gives the artist and the first letter of each word of the title of the song in python. The songs have to be chosen from random from an external file and the user has to guess the song.

I have made a text file with all the names and have used the `readlines()` function to get the songs from the text file.

The problem I have is that the input does not equal to the line of the file even when it the exact same.

Here is the code:

```
random_number = random.randint(0,10)
name_of_songs = open("Names of songs.txt", "r")
song = str(name_of_songs.readlines()[random_number])
name_of_songs.close()
answer = input("what is the name of the song: ")
if answer == song:
    print("well done you got 3 points")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your code is here:

```
str(name_of_songs.readlines()[random_number])
```

The `readlines()` method will return a list of lines from the file, with a trailing `'\n'` at the end of all but the last lines. For example, file:

```
Apple
Banana
Cherry
```

will be returned like:

```
['Apple\n', 'Banana\n', 'Cherry']
```

So if the user inputs `'Apple'`, the result is `'Apple'` does not equal `'Apple\n'`.

You can fix the problem by using `.read().splitlines()`, which will return a list without `'\n'`s.

**Also, using `open()` and then `close()` is a bad practice. Instead, use a `with` statement:**

```
random_number = random.randint(0,10)

with open("Names of songs.txt", "r") as name_of_songs:
    song = name_of_songs.read()splitlines()[random_number] # Note that since read returns strings, there is no need to convert it to a string again

answer = input("What is the name of the song: ")
if answer == song:
    print("well done you got 3 points")
```

Answer (score 0):

code like this:

```
import csv
name_of_songs = open("Names of songs.txt", "r")
reader=csv.reader(name_of_songs)
for eachRow in reader:
    //you will get each line here (eachRow)
```